# Iterar dos funciones en un bucle for con bash

Tags: bash, shell

Estoy teniendo problemas al intentar iterar entre una función y otra. Es decir, iterar sin generar un salto de linea para que tenga una intermitencia.

```
#!/bin/bash

hola(){
    echo -e "${color} HOLA"
    echo -e "${color} HOLA"
    echo -e "${color} HOLA"
}

adios(){
    echo -e "${color} ADIOS"
    echo -e "${color} ADIOS"
    echo -e "${color} ADIOS"
}

bucle(){

x=0
    while [ $x -le 4 ];do
        for i in  hola  adios ; do
            sleep 0.5 &&  echo -e -n "\r$i"
        done
        x=$[ $x + 1 ]
    done
}

bucle
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para imprimir las tres líneas de un función y luego cambiarlas de forma intermitente por las líneas de otra función, no se me ocurre alguna manera en bash pero si para alternar de una función a otra.

Cuando hagas pongas el `echo` dentro del `for`, puedes utilizar un *command substitution* con el nombre de la función entre los caracteres `$( función )`

```
#!/bin/bash

hola() {
    echo -e "${color} HOLA "
}

adios() {
    echo -e "${color} ADIOS"
}

bucle() {

    x=0
    while [ $x -le 4 ];do
        for i in hola adios; do
            sleep 0.5
            echo -ne "\r$($i)"
        done
        ((x++))
    done
}

bucle
```

Además de que en la función `hola` puedes añadir un espacio extra para que reemplace los caracteres que le faltan para igualar a los ya impresos con `ADIOS`. Es decir, "ADIOS" tiene 5 caracteres y "HOLA" 4, por lo que cuando se regrese al inicio del renglón y se pinte el "HOLA" sobre lo ya pintado por el "ADIOS", sobrará la letra "S" del "ADIOS". Entonces puedes pintar un espacio para que lo oculte.

### Actualización.

Traté de buscar información para poder volver n líneas atrás y [encontré](https://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x361.html) que el caracter `\033[<numero de lineas>A` desplaza una cantidad de número de líneas hacía arriba, es decir `\033[2A` desplazaría 2 hacía arriba, por lo que tu código podría quedar de la siguiente manera.

```
#!/bin/bash

hola() {
    echo -e "\033[2A${color} HOLA "
    echo -e "${color} HOLA "
    echo -e "${color} HOLA "
}

adios() {
    echo -e "\033[2A${color} ADIOS"
    echo -e "${color} ADIOS"
    echo -e "${color} ADIOS"
}

bucle() {
    clear
    x=0
    while [ $x -le 4 ];do
        for i in hola adios; do
            sleep 0.5
            echo -ne "\r$($i)"
        done
        ((x++))
    done
}

bucle
```

Imprimiendo el banner de la función `hola` que sobreescribe al banner de la función `adios`.